# If condition not working properly on angular with node backend (MEAN Stack)

Tags: angular, mean-stack

My Problem is when I clicked the Register button with the text field date my code worked just fine. According to my code new user is registered in MongoDB using my node backend and redirect the home page within 2 seconds.

But the problem is when I clicked the register button with no data in the text field  (Just clicked my register button on the front end)--:  Just redirect home screen within two seconds.

But, it shouldn't redirect to the home screen without any registration.
How can I Fix This Problem?

This Is My Front End:

```html
<form  [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input aria-describedby="emailHelp" class="form-control" formControlName="email" id="exampleInputEmail1"
           name="email"
           placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="username" id="exampleInputUserName" name="username" placeholder="User Name"
           type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="password" id="exampleInputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password"
           type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="processing" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my *register.component.spec.ts Function:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {


  form!: FormGroup;
  message: any;
  messageClass: any;
  processing = false;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private routers:Router
  ) {
    this.createForm()
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }


  onRegisterSubmit() {
    this.processing = true
    this.disableForm()
    const user = {
      email: this.form.get('email')?.value,
      username: this.form.get('username')?.value,
      password: this.form.get('password')?.value
    }
    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if (!data) {
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'
      
        this.processing = false
        this.enableForm()
      } else {
        this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'
        
        setTimeout(()=>{
          (<any>this.routers).navigate(['/home']);
        },2000)
      }
    })
  }
```

This is my auth.service.ts File:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  domain = "http://localhost:3000"
  authToken: any
  user: any


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  registerUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/register', user)
  }
```

Comment: So what does node return when the user is empty?

Comment: node returns nothing...Just redirect my home page..I can't find out what's wrong with my code. please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't check if the form is valid, you have to do that manully before submiting. So in `onRegisterSubmit()` wrap your code in the following:

```
onRegisterSubmit() {
  // this runs the validators
  this.form.markAllAsTouched();
  if (this.form.valid) {
  //Add your code here
  }
}
```